# What is the 'name' field used for in the definition of a theano shared variable?

Tags: python, theano

I notice that you can define a theano shared variable by:

```
theano.shared(value, name=None, strict=False, allow_downcast=None, **kwargs)
```

In theano doc [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/shared.html#module-shared), it says the name field is "the name for this variable". I see in most cases people just pass a exactly same string to the name field as the shared variable's name in Python. For example:

```
a = theano.shared(1, "a")
```

What is the rule of thumb to define the name field? What is the name field used for?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning names to Theano objects helps during debugging. For example, `theano.printing.debugprint` will include the name, if present, in its output; this can make understanding a complex computation graph easier.

You can also give names to input variables (e.g. `x=theano.tensor.scalar('x')`) and functions (e.g. `f=theano.function(inputs, outputs, name='f')`.

The output of `theano.printing.debugprint` can be limited by naming nodes whose content you don't need to see and using the `stop_on_name` parameter.

Keep Python names and Theano names in sync can be tedious and error prone. In some circumstances you might like to use functions such as:

```
def name_node(variable, variable_names):
    for name, query_variable in variable_names.iteritems():
        if query_variable is variable:
            variable.name = name

    return variable


def name_nodes(variables, variable_names):
    if not isinstance(variables, (tuple, list)):
        return name_node(variables, variable_names)

    for variable in variables:
        for name, query_variable in variable_names.iteritems():
            if query_variable is variable:
                variable.name = name

    return variables
```

In a symbolic function you can use these like this:

```
def create_graph(w_filename):
    x = T.scalar()
    w = theano.shared(numpy.load(w_filename))
    y = T.tanh(theano.dot(x, w))
    return name_nodes([x, w, y], locals())
```

This is a bit of a Python hack and won't be suitable in all circumstances.

Comment: Can you please give a simple examples where use of names is very much helpful? Thanks